# Time series with twice daily frequency in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have some data coming from sensors with observations every 12 hours. I want to analyze it as time series, but I not sure what frequency to use to convert it to time series. The `ts` function needs a start, an end and a frequency. `ts(data, start = 1, end = numeric(), frequency = 1,...)`

I do not want to aggregate it to once daily frequency (will likely lose some information). Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

The `ts` class does not handle high frequency data very well. I suggest you use the `tsibble` class instead. See https://cran.r-project.org/package=tsibble. There are many modelling tools designed for `tsibble` objects provided by the `feasts` and `fable` packages.